# iOS change font size programmatically not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 7.0f) {
            self.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }

        _topUserNewName= [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _topUserNewName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        _topUserNewName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _topUserNewName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelvaticaNeue-Regular" size:5.0];
        _topUserNewName.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(47/255.0) green:(55/255.0) blue:(65/255.0) alpha:1];
        _topUserNewName.frame = CGRectMake(66, 8, 215, 21);


        _topUserName= [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _topUserName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        _topUserName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _topUserName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelvaticaNeue-Regular" size:10.0];
        _topUserName.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(145/255.0) green:(212/255.0) blue:(210/255.0) alpha:1];
        _topUserName.frame = CGRectMake(66, 37, 210, 21);


        [self.contentView addSubview:_topUserNewName];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_topUserName];


        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This codes in my table cell class. I want to change font size with programmatically right here when i change size nothing change ? 
i researched on google this rule is right but not work any idea ?

Comment: Is any of it working, or just not the font? How are you using the cell?

Comment: everything is ok,only font not work

Comment: Have you checked you get a font back when you request for `HelvaticaNeue-Regular`? I don't remember but the font name could be wrong.

Comment: i tried @"System" still not work

Comment: so how are you using it + testing it?

Comment: if i write `_topUserNewName.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:5.0];` font size changed but also i want to change font type too

Comment: Oh, I see in the previous comment you actually mean you tried the string `@"System"` - you need to use the correct font name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `HelveticaNeue-Regular`does not actually exist. This should be `[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelvaticaNeue" size:10.0];`.

You can see the list of all font names here : http://iosfonts.com/

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are passing the right font family and font face..try this

```
 [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10.0];
```

HelvticaNeue-Regular face is not suported by ios, you can check all supported fonts by enumerating as:

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]){ NSLog(@"Font Family = %@",familyName);
for (NSString *fontName in
[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]){ NSLog(@"\t%@", fontName);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**/*===FOR IOS8===*/**

```
static NSString *_myCustomFontName;

+ (NSString *)myCustomFontName
{

    if ( !_myCustomFontName )

    {

        NSArray *arr = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Custom Font Family"];
        // I know I only have one font in this family
        if ( [arr count] > 0 )
            _myCustomFontName = arr[0];        
    }

   return _myCustomFontName;
}
```